# How do I refresh a ReferenceManyField while remaining on the page?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Hi and thanks in advance! Admin on Rest is a great base to start from to quickly build simple REST admins. I have a scenario where I would like to display and edit related records without leaving the parent. e.g Editing the Options of a Multiple Choice Question from the Question Edit View.

I have managed to implement a modal dialog that allows me to create/edit the Options(passed along as a record prop), however I'm stuck at trying to refresh the list of options on the Question View once I have successfully saved the Option.

I'm relatively new to React. Would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

`ReferenceManyField` doesn't provide controls for filtering or pagination. However, it's quite straightforward to create some. Start by creating your own component using `ReferenceManyField` as a base. Store the page, sort, and filter as properties. Add methods that change these properties and re-trigger `fetchReferences`. Add buttons (pagination, filtering, etc) that trigger these methods.

But if you'r new to React, this won't be easy. I suggest you learn React first.

Comment: Thanks! by "using `ReferenceManyField` as a base" do you mean extending it like `class ReferenceManyFieldWithRefresh extends ReferenceManyField` then calling fetchReferences when needed? Are there any quick examples of extending Admin on Rest components I could take a look at?

Comment: Yes, you can extend, or create your own class by copying the code.